# Why is $routeParams undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a service to handle an http request:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('stats', function($http){
            return {
                getStats: function(path) {
                    return $http
                       .get(path)
                       .then(function(result) {
                            //resolve the promise as the data
                            return result.data;
                        });
                }
            };
    });
```

When the getStats method is called in the controller however, the $routeParams property is undefined so the request never runs:

```
app.controller('ChartController', ['$route', 'stats', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function($route, stats, $scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {

  console.log($routeParams);

  var path = "/players/players/" + $routeParams.playerId;

  var players = stats.getStats(path);
```

This isn't a problem I experience when I simply run the http request directly in the controller, without using a service.

Comment: Could you please share the route defined and the URL.

Comment: The route would be something like "players#/485/" with the three digit number at the end varying.

Comment: How is the $routeProvider defined ???

Comment: @Jack - Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yeah, just commented it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that there was no problem without the service which means the problem is not with the routeParams, but with the way you are handing your service. The problem is the async behavior of AJAX calls. The response is returned prior to response received. There are many ways to fix this. I am going to explain one possible way.

Update your factory to

```
angular.module('app')
        .factory('stats', function($http){
            return{
                getStats: function(path) {
          return $http.get(path);
        }
            };
        });
```

Update controller as

```
var players;
stats.getStats(path).then(function(response){
      players = response.data;
});
```

Other possible options can be using `$q` service or using callback functions.

Comment: @Jack - Good to hear that. You can always mark the answer as accepted for future reference.